# Request for Identification

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

The tenth skanda of Bhagavatha Purana mentions the places Balarama visited during His pilgrimage. Specifically, in the South, it is mentioned that He visited, Shri Shaila, Tirumala, Shrirangam, Kanchipuram, Kamakoshni (the present day Kumbhakonam) and Madurai. It also mentions Balarama's visit to Rshabhadri, a Vishnu kshetra. I quote the verse from Bhagavatha

> ऋषभाद्रिं हरे: क्षेत्रं दक्षिणां मथुरां तथा ।
>
> सामुद्रं सेतुमगमत्महापातकनाशनम् ॥

Is the Rshabhadri mentioned in the sloka the present day Melukote in Karnataka? Sthalapurana of Melukote has it that Balarama visited Melukote during His pilgrimage and installed the procession deity Ramapriya. Hence this question.

Comment: needs a better title

Answer (score 2):

Rshabhadri or Vrishabhari is Alagar koil near the present day Madurai. Vadiraja swamy has mentioned this place in his [Teertha prabhanda](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/downloads/Yathiraja%20Vadirajas%20Theertha%20Prabandha.pdf).
Yama, the God of Death, is said to have worshipped Lord Vishnu here in the form of a bull and hence the name Vrishabhachala or Vrishabhadri.